# log4j not logging to some files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I've seen many questions concerning log4j not writing **any** files, but my problem is that, log4j **does** (seem to) work, but not for all files.

My configuration is as follows (I have omitted a few loggers for simplicity, the below lines appear in the order they are in in the file):

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# this logger works without any problems
log4j.appender.errorFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorFile.File=${LOG_HOME}/errors.log
log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.errorFile.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.errorFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.errorFile.Threshold=ERROR

# this file is created but always empty
log4j.appender.barcodeScanner=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.barcodeScanner.File=${LOG_HOME}/barcodeScanner.log
log4j.appender.barcodeScanner.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.barcodeScanner.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.barcodeScanner.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.barcodeScanner.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# this logger also works
log4j.appender.DoubleDtpaList=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DoubleDtpaList.File=${LOG_HOME}/DoubleDtpaList.log
log4j.appender.DoubleDtpaList.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.DoubleDtpaList.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.DoubleDtpaList.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DoubleDtpaList.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=error, errorFile
log4j.logger.scanner.BarcodeScanner=debug, barcodeScanner
log4j.logger.util.DetectDoubles=trace, DoubleDtpaList
```

Using the logger within the `BarcodeScanner` class yields correct results when using `logger.error()` (this logs to the errors.log file), but all calls to `logger.debug()` and `logger.info()` have no effect.

The variable `LOG_HOME` is passed as an argument/option when executing the *.jar file.

**EDIT 1**: I added another (working) logger/appender configuration for clarification. Another piece of information I unfortunately left out ist that I want all logs for the scanner to go to the barcodeScanner.log file (with the errors additionally going to errors.log (root Logger)

Comment: `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT`

Comment: @Ved wouldn't that just output it all to stdout? I want the errors logged by log4j to go to the file; stdout and stderr are piped to different files.

Comment: "but all calls to logger.debug() and logger.info() have no effect." This will not be resolved if you don't write DEBUG there.

Comment: @Ved Shouldn't the level setting for BarcodeScanner "overrule" the one for the rootLogger? I don't want all debug output going into my error logs, hence why the rootLogger is set to ERROR.

Comment: I just added some additional information that may help clarify my problem. I'm afraid I may have caused confusion by listing only the root logger and the non-working logger, sorry.